# What functions can be approximated by homogeneous rational functions with numerator and denominator of the same degree?

Tags: polynomials, approximation, weierstrass-approximation

Consider homogeneous polynomials $P(X,Y)$ in two variables. According to [Approximation by homogeneous polynomials by Totik](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904513001226), "every even continuous function on a centrally symmetric convex curve can be uniformly approximated by homogeneous polynomials".

My question is the following: can all (even?) continuous functions be approximated by homogeneous rational functions with numerator and  denominator of the same degree? If not, which can be?

Comment: In particular, can anything be said about $P(X,Y)/X^{d}$ for example?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I see what you mean and what I am looking for comes down to "asking what can be approximated by all rational homogeneous functions with the numerator and denominator of the same degree? ".   Thanks again!